# async pipe sends 'null' value to the child component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-pipe, async-pipe

I want to pass a value to the child component. this value is an Observable, so I use async pipe.

```
<child [test]="test$ | async"></child>
```

test$ is just a normal observable variable, that emits values after a period of time (3000 ms), simulating an API request to the server.

```
this.test$=timer(3000).pipe(
      mapTo("value")      
 )
```

in child component, I just want to check `test` value

```
@Input() test: any;

constructor(){
    console.log("child/test", this.test); //null
    setTimeout(()=>console.log("child/test (timeout)", this.test),4000) //value

   if(this.test){
     //maintain and check `this.test`
     //this code will not run, because at this point `this.test` is null.
     //we don't know the exact time that `this.test` will have a value
     //this causes that `this.test` is wrong

      this.checked=true 
     }
  }
```

```
<div *ngIf="checked">{{test}}</div>
```

I don't want to change the type of test to be `Observable` and subscribe to it.
I want to receive the final value directly.
and I don't want to modify the edit component at all.

using `ChangeDetectorRef` to manually trigger the change detector is not

```
@Input() test$:Observable

constructor(){
  this.test$.subscribe(v=>this.test=v)
}
```

I also made this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formobj-7520?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.ts) to check the value changing among all the compoonent's hooks.

Answer (score 21):

Much easier solution:

```
(test$ | async) || defaultTestValue
```

Answer (score 19):

`async` pipe will return `null` when no value is emitted by `Observable` yet. So, the value of `test` in child component is:

- `undefined` in constructor because `@Input()` variables are not assigned at this state
- `null` after that (e.g. first `onChanges` hook or `onInit` hook`) when no value is emitted by the Observable
- `value` when the Observable emit new value

Now, you should either create child component only when `test` variable is not `null` with `*ngIf`, or handle correctly the state of child component with nullable `test` (e.g. Add a progress bar when `test` is null). The choice is up to you.

Answer (score 15):

### app.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(test$ | async) as test; else defaultTmpl">
    <child [test]="test"></child>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #defaultTmpl>Default Template</ng-template>
```

For more details please take a look:
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-async-pipe

Comment: this is a very good idea, but actually I want to send `test` directly to the child component even it don't have a value yet. this makes the child component display a default template until `test` get it's value without the need to implement a default template myself in my parent component.

Comment: Okay, another solution is to use `ngOnChanges()` hook to track changes in your `@Input()`. It would minor changes in child component however you can properly track input params.
Take a look please: https://dev.to/nickraphael/ngonchanges-best-practice-always-use-simplechanges-always-1feg

Comment: @Alexander - Please note that he doesn't want to modify the child component at all.

Comment: @ConnorsFan - anyway he has to make some adjustments due to the fact that he wants to apply switching between `default` template and template with data in the child component

Answer (score 4):

You can use the rxjs operator *startWith* to set an initial value for your observable. If incase you want an custom starting value.

```
this.test$=timer(3000).pipe(
  mapTo("value"),
  startWith(0))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create variable inside your template like this:

```
test$ | async; let test;
```

then later you can check:

`*ngIf='test'`

if it is true then you can render your child component.

Comment: Inside your parent component. Then you use simply `ngIf` to check if `test` is anything else than `undefined` or `null` and if so, you pass it to child component.