# BehaviorSubject<any[]> throwing Type 'any[] | null' is not assignable to type 'any[]' error

Tags: angular, typescript

When passing a BehaviorSubject that is stored in my CacheService to a component @Input() which expects any[], an error any[] | Type 'any[] | null' is not assignable to type 'any[]' error is thrown, even though the behavior subject is instantiated with a default value of an empty array in a service, I'm unsure as to why this occurs, below is the abridged version of my app to recreate the issue, any help would be much appreciated.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-custom-select [options]="this.items$ | async"></app-custom-select>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { CacheService } from './services/cache.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent 
{
    items$ = this.cache.items.data$;
    constructor(private cache: CacheService) {}
}
```

**cache.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CacheArray } from '../models/CacheArray';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CacheService 
{
    items = new CacheArray<any>();
}
```

**cache.ts**

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from "rxjs";

export class CacheArray<T>
{
    data$ = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>([]);

    load(obs: Observable<T[]>)
    {
        obs.subscribe((items: T[]) => {
            this.data$.next(items);
        });
    }
}
```

**custom-select.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-select',
  templateUrl: './custom-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-select.component.scss']
})
export class CustomSelectComponent
{
    @Input()
    options: any[] = [];
}
```

I expected that the error wouldn't be thrown

Comment: Your code does not have `@Input()`, please post minimal reproducible example.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681239/async-pipe-sends-null-value-to-the-child-component) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

BehaviorSubject is a subject which assigna the lateast value to all of there subscriber, when we create the behaviour object then we must be assign the initial value to the object as well.

So possiblity if this error is like your initial value is some `any[]` and you try to assign the `null` value while update the object.

If you add a check before assign the value in the BehaviourSubject then possiblly error will resolved

```
if(items != null) {
    this.data$.next(items);
}
```